# Hibernate Search for date

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search, infinispan

I'm using Hibernate Search 4.4.0 in Infinispan. I'm trying to search the date of inserting docs. And I have saved date in type String.

This is the definition of date in my class:

```
private String ins = Constants.dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

And the dateFormat is:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Now I mapping this field like:

```
mapping.entity(Entity.class)
   .property("ins", ElementType.FIELD).field().analyze(Analyze.NO);
```

I have verified that there are objects in my cache whose date property is `2012-09-17 14:28:32.0`. But when I use query like:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("ins").matching("2012-09-17").creatQuery();
```

to search in cache, there is no result.

Is there something I messed up??

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the index using Luke to see what value is being stored in the `ins` field?

Comment: I have checked the value of 'ins' field, it seems like in type '2012-09-17 14:28:32.0' in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Hibernate Search, but I think that instead of

> > .analyze(Analyze.NO)

you shall write

> > .analyze(Analyze.NOT_TOKENIZED)

or alike

Comment: Ty for the response, but I didn't find the option for 'NOT_TOKENIZED' in infinispan.

Comment: according to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/api/org/hibernate/search/annotations/Analyze.html it should be `Analyze.YES`

Comment: After I use anlyzer for 'ins' field, when I search '2012-09-17', it was seperated into '2012', '09', '17'. But there isn't any result found by query.

Comment: ok, then it seems to be correct with `Analyze.NO`. Try using a `wildcard` or `prefix` query. When you look for `matching("2012-09-17")` it looks for exact matches, which in your case is
`2012-09-17 14:28:32.0`. In order to find it you need to run a query `2012-09-17*`

Comment: What @injecteer said.  Since your field is being stored down to the millisecond, you'll need to use a `.wildcard()` clause in your `QueryBuilder`.  Alternatively (and this might be better), you may want to figure out why the index is storing the time, and fix that so that it's only the date.  Hibernate Search provides `DateBridge`s to transform `Date`s to `String`s that automatically resolve to the precision you specify.

Comment: Like both of u said, I tried use **wildcard** query `2012*` or `2012-09-17*`, there is nothing in the result. I'm so confused. **PS**:I'm doing the internship in the company. They have defined `ins` in type `String`, so I needn't use the `DataBridge` for that field. And I dont understand that `ins` is in format "yyyy-MM-dd", why there is "HH:mm:ss" in the cache?

Comment: I'm so sry that I find in the wrong field. Thx for all reponses.